# How to display lines of a text in a terminal console with cleared screen at the bottom

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Do you know a Linux command or a parameter of a Linux command for xterm (Terminal) or Konsole, which displays lines from top to down and when the end of the screen is reached, the screen will be cleared before the next line will be displayed? E.g.
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
...
25.
-----clear screen---
26.
27.

Is it also possible to slow down displaying every text line? Is it possible to slow down printing lines and clearing screen at the bottom of screen?

Thank you in advance.

-Linuxfluesterer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
while true; do
    echo $((c++))
    (( c % $(tput lines) == 0)) && clear
    sleep .1
done
```

Check http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

### Edit :

version with files :

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    (( c % $(tput lines) == 0)) && clear
    ((c++))
    sleep .1
done < <(cat file1 file2 file3)
```

Comment: First, thanks for the quick reply.
But sorry, this example doesn't clear the screen, only displaying lines and then the lines are moved up (scrolled up). Clear is not executed.
Second, I would like to simply output any text file with a clear screen at the bottom edge.

Comment: Copied/pasted wrong version of the script, try again

Comment: I did again. Working now, numbers are displayed and at the end of screen the screen is cleared before continuing. Fine!
But now, how to display any text file this behavior?
p.s. I did not downgrade you, honestly!

Comment: Check my edited post

Comment: #!/bin/bash

c=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    (( c % $(tput lines) == 0)) && clear
    sleep .5
done < <(cat /home/linuxfluesterer/systemprotocol.txt)

exit

...doesn't work, only black screen...

maybe missing a c++?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Post edited

Comment: Finally that c++ did the trick. Thanks for help. I'm glad now...